# How to set default_app_config for Django with apps directory structure?

Tags: python, django

I want to declare `default_app_config` variable for my app, but I have an error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'accounts'.
>   Check that 'apps.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig.name' is correct.

All my apps is located in directory apps:

```
project_name/
apps/
   app1/
   app2/
   ....
   accounts/
```

I am using my apps like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # Local Apps
  'apps.category',
  'apps.products',
  'apps.cart',
  'apps.orders',
  'apps.accounts',
  'apps.attributes',
  'apps.pages',
  'apps.compare',
  'apps.filters',
  'apps.brands'
]
```

And now when I want to set `default_app_config` for my app, I get the error above.

`__init__.py` in app folder:

```
default_app_config = 'apps.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig'
```

`apps.py` in app folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'
    verbose_name = 'Пользователи'
```

Why I get the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AppConfig name is full python path to the application. So try...

```
name = 'apps.accounts'
```